# tensorflow_model_server: command not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've created a folder "Model_en" and the path to my saved model is:
**"--model_base_path=/Users/tarunkumar/Documents/tensor_models/Model_en/1/"**

also, my model name is:
**"--model_name=Model_en"**

After running the command:
**"tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=Model_en --model_base_path=/Users/tarunkumar/Documents/tensor_models/Model_en/1/
"**

I'm getting the error as:
**"bash: tensorflow_model_server: command not found"**

Comment: Did you install the server? https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup

Answer (score 1):

The installation may not have happen properly. For safer side, first remove the corrupt packages that may have installed,

```
apt-get remove tensorflow-model-server
```

Then,

1. Add TensorFlow Serving distribution URI as a package source:

   `echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

To this, you should get `OK` as output in the terminal.

2. Install and update TensorFlow ModelServer:

   `apt-get update && apt-get install tensorflow-model-server`
3. Once installed, upgrade to a newer version of tensorflow-model-server with:

   `apt-get upgrade tensorflow-model-server`

The binary can now be invoked using the command `tensorflow_model_server`

You may get output,

```
Failed to start server. Error: Invalid argument: Both server_options.model_base_path and server_options.model_config_file are empty!
```

This means the installation is successful and you can run the command to start the server.

[source](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup)

Answer (score 0):

This may help as well, at least it worked for me.

```
pip install tensorflow-serving-api
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it first. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup) is how it is done on Debian/Ubuntu:

Installation
Add TensorFlow Serving distribution URI as a package source (one time setup)

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install and update TensorFlow ModelServer

```
apt-get update && apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
```

Once installed, the binary can be invoked using the command tensorflow_model_server.

You can upgrade to a newer version of tensorflow-model-server with:

```
apt-get upgrade tensorflow-model-server
```